# AJAX call returning empty object from json_encode

Tags: php, ajax, json, pivot.js

I'm making an AJAX call to a fairly simple PHP function. The response should be a JSON object to be manipulated, but my response is always an empty object.

Relevant Code:

index.html's AJAX Call:

```
$( function() {
    $('#dates').on('submit', function (e) {
        var start_time = new Date().getTime();
        e.preventDefault();
        var submitData = $('#dates').serialize();
        console.log(submitData);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'inflow.php',
            data:$('#dates').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#loading').hide();
            },
            error:function(xhr, desc, err){
                alert('You tried to send an AJAX request, but something went wrong.\n Please Contact the NASR WebDev Team');
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log("Details: " + desc +"\nError: "+ err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

inflow.php's array creation and echo:

```
<?php

$msqlStart = $_POST['start_date'];
$msqlEnd = $_POST['end_date'];

$inflowQuery=
    "SELECT
        COUNT,
        QUEUE_ID,
        QUEUE_GROUP,
        INFLOW_DATE,
        LINE_OF_BUSINESS
    FROM
        ticket_inflow.inflow
    WHERE
        ROUTE_STATUS = 'Inflow'
        AND inflow_date between ? and ?";

    $connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
    if ($connect->connect_error){
        die("Failed to Connect:.".$connect->connect_errno.": ".$connect->connect_error);
    }
    if(!($statment = $connect->prepare($inflowQuery))){
        die('Error in Preparation Error Number:%d Error: %s');
    }
    if(!$statment->bind_param('ss', $msqlStart, $msqlEnd)){
        die ('Error in Binding');
    }
    if(!$statment->execute()){
        die('Error In Execution');
    }
    $statment->bind_result($inflowCount, $inflowQueue, $inflowQG, $inflowDate, $inflowLOB);

    $a_json = array();
    $jsonRow = array();

    While($statment->fetch()){
        $UID = 0;
        $jsonRow['UID'] = $UID++;
        $jsonRow['count'] = utf8_encode($inflowCount);
        $jsonRow['inflow_date'] = utf8_encode($inflowDate);
        $jsonRow['queue'] = utf8_encode($inflowQueue);
        $jsonRow['queue_group'] = utf8_encode($inflowQG);
        $jsonRow['lob'] = utf8_encode($inflowLOB);
        array_push($a_json, $jsonRow);
    }


    $jsonReturn = json_encode($a_json);

    echo $jsonReturn;
```

?>

If I go directly to inflow.php and pass it parameter's identical to what the page passes it, I get what appears to be a nice JSON object, however when I look at the response Chrome Developer's Tools I get:

```
[]
```

And nothing more.

Comment: looks like your $statment->fetch() isn't triggering the while

Comment: Why are you using `contentType: "application/json"`? You are sending a url encoded text string so you shouldn't use that.

Comment: @Rooster That was my initial thought, however, visiting the php page directly echoes what looks like a valid JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending form data, not json;

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'inflow.php',
        data:$('#dates').serialize(),
        //contentType: "application/json",<-- remove this
        dataType: 'json',
```

Comment: I think that was a left over from my troubleshooting. Even with it removed I'm still getting an empty array.

Comment: I've added the full PHP, minus the actual login credentials for the server. When I fire an identical while with $testRows filled with garbage, it seems to pass the JSON correctly.

Comment: @Sugarcaen Did you say this page (inflow.php) returns a result when visited directly in a browser?

Comment: Yes. When I go to inflow.php?start_date&end_date I get what appears to be valid JSON object (At least, JSON Lint passes it.)

Comment: @Sugarcaen Visiting the page in the browser would result in `$msqlStart` and `$msqlEnd` being `null` (`$_POST` would be empty for a get request), so i expect that parameters you are sending via ajax are badly formed - did you try hardcoding the values in php to test

Comment: Yes, I previously set default dates with the same result. I've also tried passing Start and End via URL.

Comment: I hadn't tried it on the HTML page with hardcoded values, only the php. It looks like you're right, something strange is going on with the way AJAX is handling the parameters.

Comment: When switched to $_REQUEST[] instead of $_POST[], the entire page functions normally. I'm marking this as answered as you helped locate the root of the issue.

Comment: @Sugarcaen Glad you got it working, though that does seem strange.